# I'm a javascript beginner and I can't get this code to run on the browser

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I just want the getElementById to work but I can, I get this error using chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined
```

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<body>


<table>
<tr><td>Input the test variable:</td>
<td><input id="x" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>

<tr><th>Calculate the number</th>
<td><button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button></td></tr>
</table>


<script src="test1javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
window.onload=function calculate(){
var x=document.getElementById("x");
if(x==5){
alert(x);
}
}
```

Comment: Why in the world you haven't specified the input type, like: `<input type="text" />` - and I recommend using either: `onkeyup`, `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` events to watch changes in the textfield.

Comment: remove window.onload= from javascript.

Comment: @zlomerovic - `type="text"` _is_ the default. Regarding use of key event handlers, you need a blur or change handler too to allow for non-keyboard updates (cut/paste/drag'n'drop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the function on `window.onload`. Also you are binding the same function to `input onchange` and also to `button onclick`. Instead declare the function as follows and bind the function only to `button onclick`. Also notice `.value` after `document.getElementById("x")`

```
function calculate(){
  var x=document.getElementById("x").value;
  if(x==5){
    alert(x);
  }
}
```

Also better include script file in `<head></head>` and specify the `type` attribute too:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="test1javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
       <tr><td>Input the test variable:</td>
       <td><input id="x" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
       <tr><th>Calculate the number</th>
       <td><button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button></td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

`document.getElementById` returns a reference to the element (as name suggests `getElement`, but not its `value`) along with all its attributes. In above case its a button. You need to use its desired attribute to access required property
[image]

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I declared type="text" even though I thought it wasn't necessary. Then I put the window.onload at the bottom of the code which removed the errors, but I still didn't ge t the alert. I think in the end adding .value to the getElementById is what made it work. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @user2606257 Is it resolved? You could just mark it as answer.

Comment: Also why is the .value required after document.getElementById("x")?

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns a reference to the element (as name suggests `getElement`, but not its value) along with all its attributes. You need to use its desired attribute to access required property. I modified the answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

you should first define your function, then use onload:

```
function calculate(){
   var x=document.getElementById("x");
   if(x==5){
      alert(x);
   }
}
window.onload = calculate;
```

Comment: I think you could probably omit the `onload` part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `calculate` on its own:

```
function calculate() {
    // Added .value because you want the content and not the object itself
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    if (x == 5) {
        alert(x);
    }
}
```

Then to add it to the `window.onload` event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', calculate);
```